# Can I save a backbone model in WebSql with predefined Id?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, identifier, web-sql

For some reasons, I'm having to first inserting a model in the server by an ajax call and then save it to **WebSql**.

The Id that I get in the ajax reply is needed to be the Id of the WebSql record too.

However, it seems **backbone** is creating another Id while saving the record in WebSql.

Is there a way to pre-specify that **Id** which is being saved in WebSql?

Thanks in advance.

(Just thought of another question: How does backbone syncs the 'Id' property in front database and back-end database?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `{wait: true}` when saving.  What this does is that it'll change the current model with the response values from the API call.  This will parse that response and hopefully that response contains this newly created "ID". So looks like this:

```
var model = this.model;
model.save(null, { wait: true, success: function(){
  console.log(model.id)
}})
```